# Auto populating FKs

Tags: sql, sql-server, create-table, insert-into

Okay so I am playing around with setting up a new small DB. After laying it all out on the white board I have started to create it in SQL Server. I have gotten all my tables created with their associated PKs and FKs. However when I go to INSERT data into these tables I would like my PKs and FKs to auto populate which I thought I had setup during table creation. For example lets say I have 3 columns, one is PK, and another is a FK. When I INSERT INTO this table a new record, I would like to only have to specify information for the 3rd column name that is a non PK/FK and have the PK auto increment, and allow for a FK to be null.

[image]

The CREATE statement I used was:

```
CREATE TABLE CONSOLE
(
     consoleID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
     consoleName VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
     userID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES USER(userID)
);
```

So when I go to add a record I would like to use:

```
INSERT INTO CONSOLE
VALUES ('Xbox');
```

Comment: What's the point of a foreign key constraint if you are going to allow null values?

Comment: And how should the DB magically know to which user you refer when you insert `Xbox`? Of course you have to provide a value for the foreign key.

Comment: @P.Salmon I think he wants to populate with NULL value and he will update it later.

Comment: `I would like my PKs and FKs to auto populate which I thought I had setup during table creation` Can you show us how you do this ?

Comment: @P.Salmon *"What's the point of a foreign key constraint if you are going to allow null values? "* That scenario is needed to achieve a relationship to 0 or 1 record. For example you could represent monogamy by having a nullable FK from a person to their spouse. However I fully support that in this scenario `userID` being nullable is unlikely to be intended, which is probably what you were trying to say.

Comment: Yeah I am just confused because creating an ERD with tables linking via FKs make perfect sense to me on paper, but when it comes to building your tables out in practice, it doesnt quite make sense to me. Do most people add FK when they are building a table or add it after the fact? Also should you do this via a new query or using the GUI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope that you will be populating the FK value later, by updating the table. Because, the RDBMS will not automatically populate FK value for you.

Create the table with default value for FK as NULL, as given below.

```
CREATE TABLE CONSOLE(
    consoleID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    consoleName VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    userID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES USER(userID) DEFAULT NULL 
);
```

When you insert into the table, specify the column name. Now, the PK will be auto incremented value and FK will be NULL.

```
INSERT INTO CONSOLE(ConsoleName)
VALUES ('Xbox');
```

**EDIT**

I see from comments that you want to auto populate PK and FK. Auto populating FK is not possible. You can do that through two means:

1. Write a AFTER INSERT trigger, which will find the right FK value and INSERT into the table.
2. Write a stored procedure with parameters for insert. Get the value for ConsoleName and find the right FK value and INSERT into the table as given below.

`DECLARE @rightUserId INT; -- Find value for this
 INSERT INTO CONSOLE(ConsoleName, UserId)
    VALUES ('Xbox',@rightUserId);`

Comment: Okay that makes sense. I guess my main question, is what is the best way to do foreign keys then? I am an entry level developer and have done a lot of charts of building databases with ERD's but when you actually build it, what is the best way to link foreign keys? I guess I am getting confused because I was always taught a FK is a PK of another table so how could it be a null FK if it cannot be null as a PK for another table? Are all FK manually entered?

Comment: @J33NO, Yes. Foreign keys are manually entered as part of insert statement or found from the parent table and then inserted into the child table, as part of statements(ad-hoc or part of stored procedure or trigger)